# Automatic offset / alignment in CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I've a five column grid, which has in some cases only content in three columns. The content should be right aligned, so that there will be an offset of two columns. Is there a possibility to do this automatically? Actually I'm doing it with `grid-column-start: 3`,  `grid-column-start: 4`,  `grid-column-start: 5`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.col {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
</div>

<p>Actual syntax / layout:</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>

<p>Should behave like this:</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col" style="grid-column-start: 3;">1</div>
  <div class="col" style="grid-column-start: 4;">2</div>
  <div class="col" style="grid-column-start: 5;">3</div>
</div>
```

Thought about something like `justify-items: end` but thats for the alignment of the content inside the column. For me I'm looking like even more a solution as it's behaviour in flexbox (`justify-content`), but I don't want to use flexbox ;)

Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

You can handle each case alone since they aren't a lot:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.col {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.col:nth-last-child(1):first-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
.col:nth-last-child(2):first-child {
  grid-column-end: -2;
}
.col:nth-last-child(3):first-child {
  grid-column-end: -3;
}
.col:nth-last-child(4):first-child {
  grid-column-end: -4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col" >1</div>
  <div class="col" >2</div>
  <div class="col" >3</div>
  <div class="col" >4</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
</div>
```